# writing a python function to get desired value from csv

Tags: python, pandas, function

| label1 | label2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| img1_1 | img1_2 | 2 |
| img1_1 | img2_1 | 3 |
| img1_1 | img2_2 | 4 |
| img1_1 | img3_1 | 4 |
| img1_1 | img3_2 | 4 |
| img1_2 | img1_1 | 2 |
| img1_2 | img2_1 | 3 |
| img1_2 | img2_2 | 3 |
| img1_2 | img3_1 | 7 |
| img1_2 | img3_2 | 4 |
| img2_1 | img1_1 | 3 |
| img2_1 | img1_2 | 3 |
| img2_1 | img2_2 | 3 |
| img2_1 | img3_1 | 5 |
| img2_1 | img3_2 | 6 |
| img2_2 | img1_1 | 4 |
| img2_2 | img1_2 | 3 |
| img2_2 | img2_1 | 3 |
| img2_2 | img3_1 | 4 |
| img2_2 | img3_2 | 5 |
| img3_1 | img1_1 | 4 |
| img3_1 | img1_2 | 7 |
| img3_1 | img2_1 | 5 |
| img3_1 | img2_2 | 4 |
| img3_1 | img3_2 | 4 |
| img3_2 | img1_1 | 6 |
| img3_2 | img1_2 | 4 |
| img3_2 | img2_1 | 6 |
| img3_2 | img2_2 | 5 |
| img3_2 | img3_1 | 4 |

From that table I want to write a python script that will return a value like this:

```
def compute(img1,img2):
   comb1=(img1_1,img2_1)+(img1_1,img2_2)
   comb2=(img1_2,img2_1)+(img1_2,img2_2)
   return minimum(comb1,comb2)
```

I want the function to be also work with other combination. For example it should work similar for `compute(img2,img3)`, `compute(img1,img3)`. In another word,

```
  def compute(img2,img3):
       comb1=(img2_1,img3_1)+(img2_1,img3_2)
       comb2=(img2_2,img3_1)+(img2_2,img3_2) 
       return minimum(comb1,comb2)
```

What will be the easiest way to write that type of function? or how can I utilize pandas to tackle this?

I also want to create a for loop to iterate the `compute` function for every possible variable and save the result in another CSV like this:

| func | ans |
| --- | --- |
| compute(img2,img3) | 9 |
| compute(img1,img3) | 8 |
| compute(img1,img2) | 6 |

The hardship I am facing is writing the compute function which will calculate the two comb variable as I mentioned. I just want the compute function to be scalable. So that iterating the compute function through a loop gives me as many combinations as possible for the big dataset.

Comment: how is calculated for example compute(img1,img2)? I can't get 1.

Comment: Hi those values are arbitary, it should not be 1, what's the value you are getting? I did not have the time to compute manually to validate 'ans' column

Comment: i thought ans was the total, but you write that the values there are random. I am interested in the following for example: comb1=(img1_1,img2_1)+(img1_1,img2_2). img1_1 are taken from column label1 or both columns, img2_1 and img2_2 respectively from what columns?

Comment: @inquirer, thanks for notifying, I just edited the table, so from any column u take there combination will be the same, so it will not matter which column you pick, you may have same value for (label2,label1) or (label1,label2) combination. I also made the ans column correct this time by calculating manually

Comment: Replied to you with a message with a code. And yet, if img1_1 is also searched for in label2, then more than one option will be found. How to deal with this, which option to choose in this case. I have done so far what img1_1 is looking for in label1.

Comment: Understood img1_1---label1 img1_2---label2 and img1_2---label1 img1_1---label2   will give the same values. Is this the case with all combinations?

Comment: @inquirer, yes, that's correct

Comment: have you tried running the code? I got all the values, such as yours.

Comment: just in case, I made a variant that finds values for all columns and takes the first result. I also created a dataframe with results that are filled with list generators immediately in the dataframe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def compute(img1, img2):
    ferst1 = img1 + '_1'
    ferst2 = img1 + '_2'
    second1 = img2 + '_1'
    second2 = img2 + '_2'
    comb1 = df.loc[(df['label1'] == ferst1) & (df['label2'] == second1), 'value'].values[0]\
            + df.loc[(df['label1'] == ferst1) & (df['label2'] == second2), 'value'].values[0]
    comb2 = df.loc[(df['label1'] == ferst2) & (df['label2'] == second1), 'value'].values[0]\
            + df.loc[(df['label1'] == ferst2) & (df['label2'] == second2), 'value'].values[0]

    return min(comb1, comb2)

print(compute('img1', 'img2'))
```

From the arguments, four variables are created in the function with the addition of the strings '_1' and '_2'. If I guess correctly, the argument on the left looks for a match in the label1 column, the one on the right in label2. If this is not the case, please let me know. If you need to look for each argument in both columns, then there will be more than one match, which of the obtained values then choose.

**Update**

```
def compute(img1, img2):
    ferst1 = img1 + '_1'
    ferst2 = img1 + '_2'
    second1 = img2 + '_1'
    second2 = img2 + '_2'
    comb1 = df[df['label1'].isin([ferst1, second1]) & df['label2'].isin([ferst1, second1])].values[0, 2]\
            + df[df['label1'].isin([ferst1, second2]) & df['label2'].isin([ferst1, second2])].values[0, 2]
    comb2 = df[df['label1'].isin([ferst2, second1]) & df['label2'].isin([ferst2, second1])].values[0, 2]\
            + df[df['label1'].isin([ferst2, second2]) & df['label2'].isin([ferst2, second2])].values[0, 2]

    return min(comb1, comb2)


two = [['img2', 'img3'], ['img1', 'img3'], ['img1', 'img2']]
result = pd.DataFrame({'two': [",".join(i) for i in two], 'ans': [compute(i[0], i[1]) for i in two]})
print(result)
```

Output

```
         two  ans
0  img2,img3    9
1  img1,img3    8
2  img1,img2    6
```